# why there is AND operation in the last line code of my example code (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking the example code. I am not so familiar with Jquery. I never saw this kind of code in JavaScript. He is using Jquery ready function. But inside I can't understand the last line code

```
timelineComponents['eventsContent'].on('swiperight', function(){
  var mq = checkMQ();
  ( mq == 'mobile' ) && showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');});
```

Why at the end there is and operation. Is it like If condition? Does it mean that when mq is mobile, then run function showNewContent?

Here is resources code: https://codepen.io/ritz078/pen/LGRWjE

Comment: Yeah, it's like an `if`, except a lot more confusing to read. (If you have any control over the code, definitely change it to an actual `if` to make it more readable)

Comment: Used in this way `&&` is analogous to the guard operator: https://seanmonstar.com/post/707078771/guard-and-default-operators

Comment: Right. A && B returns the value A if A can be coerced into false; otherwise, it returns B. So here if (mq == 'mobile') is true then only showNewContent will be called.

Answer (score 0):

The statement checks if `mq` equals the string value `'mobile'` and if that statement is true, it will execute the function `showNewContent(..)`

It's literally the same as

```
if(mq == 'mobile') {
    showNewContent(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'prev');
}
```